# How to disable Rich Text Editor in image field caption ?

Tags: forms, media

I am using [Image Field Caption](https://drupal.org/project/image_field_caption) module. It provide a image caption field but I don't want any rich text editor appearing for the caption field. How to disable that for any specific field?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You used to be able to configure CKEditor to appear on a per-textfield basis, but apparently that's no longer possible in the 7.x-1.x versions of the [CKEditor module](https://drupal.org/project/ckeditor).

The following issue offers a JS workaround:

https://drupal.org/comment/5601364#comment-5601364